# ng-if only works when referencing var direct from service, instead of var in controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am trying to understand why my `ng-if` statement doesn't work when I reference a local variable in my controller that is assigned to a value from a service, but it works properly if assigned directly to the value from that service.

For example, this works:

```
<div class="map" ng-if="interactiveMap.mapService.esriLoaded">
    <esri-map id="map1" 
    map-options="interactiveMap.mapOptions" 
    load="interactiveMap.load"
    register-as="interactiveMap">
    </esri-map>
</div>
```

with the following controller:

```
angular.module('tamcApp')
  .controller('InteractivemapCtrl', function (map, config) {

    var self = this;
    self.map = {};

    self.mapService = map;

    self.mapOptions =  {
                    basemap: 'mcgiStreet',
                    extent: config.globals.initialExtent,
                    sliderStyle: 'small'
            };

     self.load = function(){
       map.getMap('interactiveMap').then(function(thisMap) {
         console.log(thisMap);
         self.map = thisMap;
       });

     };
  });
```

But if I were to assign the "esriLoaded" var to a local var in the scope, like this:

```
<div class="map" ng-if="interactiveMap.esriLoaded">
    <esri-map id="map1" 
    map-options="interactiveMap.mapOptions" 
    load="interactiveMap.load"
    register-as="interactiveMap">
    </esri-map>
</div>
```

Controller here:

```
angular.module('tamcApp')
  .controller('InteractivemapCtrl', function (map, config) {

    var self = this;
    self.map = {};

    self.esriLoaded = map.esriLoaded;

    self.mapOptions =  {
                    basemap: 'mcgiStreet',
                    extent: config.globals.initialExtent,
                    sliderStyle: 'small'
            };

     self.load = function(){
       map.getMap('interactiveMap').then(function(thisMap) {
         console.log(thisMap);
         self.map = thisMap;
       });

     };
  });
```

Then it doesn't work.  The value for "esriLoaded" is always false (which is the default value for esriLoaded).  It's like it isn't updating the value of `self.ersiLoaded` when the value gets updated in the "map" service.  Here is the code for the "map" service, just in case folks need it to answer this question.

```
angular.module('tamcApp')
  .service('map', function (config, esriLoader, esriRegistry, esriMapUtils) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function

    var self = this;


    self.esriLoaded = false;


    self.lazyload = function() {
      // Make a call to load Esri JSAPI resources.
      // A promise is provided for when the resources have finished loading.
      esriLoader.bootstrap({
            url: config.globals.esriJS
            }).then(function() {

                    // Set Loaded to be true
                    self.esriLoaded = true;

                    // DEFINE CUSTOM BASEMAP USED BY ALL MAPS
                    esriMapUtils.addCustomBasemap('mcgiStreet', {
                        urls: ['http://myhost.com/arcgis/rest/services/BaseMap/StreetMap/MapServer'],
                        title: 'MCGI Street Map',
                        thumbnailurl: ''
                    });


            });
    };

    if (!self.esriLoaded) {
            self.lazyload();
    }


    self.getMap = function(id){
      return esriRegistry.get(id);
    };

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually not because of angular, but because of JavaScript. `map.esriLoaded` is a `boolean` value, a primitive and thus not an object, which leads to your local `self.esriLoaded` not becoming a reference (as only objects can be referenced), but just a plain copy of the boolean value contained in `map.esriLoaded`.

A short example to make it more clear:

```
//Primitive
var a = 5; //primitive
var b = a; //b just copies the value of a

a = 6; //This will change a, but not b

conosle.log(b); //will print 5

//Object
var a = { someValue: 5 }; //a is now a reference to that object
var b = a; //b also becomes a reference to the object above

a.someValue = 1337; //will change the object a is referencing, thus also
                    //changing the object b is referencing, as its the same object

console.log(b.someValue); //will print 1337
```

Comment: @AmandaMyer Glad I could help. I would add a `isEsriLoaded()` function (returning map.esriLoaded) to your controller and bind the `ng-if` to that, that way you can bind to the actual service property without exposing the service directly to the view

Comment: yep.  That's exactly what I did after your answer.  Thank you again!